# Can't remove backslash from string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, odoo

I want to remove backslash from a string,

I tried `result.replace('\\','')` but nothing changed.

Anyone has an idea how I can remove it?

`result = '[(\'company_ids\', \'in\', company_id), (\'warehouse_ids\', \'in\', warehouse_id)]'`

Comment: Your string doesn't have actual backslashes in it... the `\'` is escaping that there's an `'` inside a string that's specified by `'`... (do `print(result)` to get the str rep of it - and you'll see...)

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes are not part of your string. They are there because you used simple quote inside a quote defined using simple quotes, but internally they are not existing. You can see it if you replace by double quotes.

```py
>>> result = '[(\'company_ids\', \'in\', company_id), (\'warehouse_ids\', \'in\', warehouse_id)]'
>>> print(result)
[('company_ids', 'in', company_id), ('warehouse_ids', 'in', warehouse_id)]
```

Answer (score -1):

it's no a part of the string but you can use `result.replace("\","")` to remove it